How to manage asynchronous race conditions when a file is mofidied in an API?
I'm developing a fullstack application using FastAPI for the backend. In this application, one or more users can query (read) a file, while multiple administrators can modify (write) it simultaneously. I'm concerned about the possibility of race conditions and other concurrency issues that might arise due to these simultaneous operations, but I don't know how to implement it in an async way, I have only used threading and multiprocessing.
Problem Details:

Users: Can query (read) the file.
Administrators: Can modify (write) the file simultaneously.

Questions:

How can I avoid race conditions when allowing multiple administrators to modify the file at the same time?
What is the best strategy to ensure data consistency when users are reading the file while administrators are modifying it?
What techniques or tools can I implement in FastAPI to handle these concurrency issues efficiently?

Additional Context:

Backend: FastAPI
Frontend: Framework could be React, Vue, etc.

I would appreciate any advice, best practices, and an implementation example to address these concurrency issues in my fullstack application. Thank you!

what kind of file? Does Sqlite help?

.txt files, my files have specific information that users can read and modify.

FastAPI is a bit out of scope for this specific problem, and doesn't have a way or mechanism specifically designed for this matter. You would need to decide what is the best way to mitigate race conditions for files generally, regardless if it's FastAPI in Python, or any other technology or language.
Do you want to lock a file for write operations (using a read-write lock) or do you want users to edit the same file at the same time (which can get pretty complicated)? If only one write is allowed, then it's just a read-write lock (i.e. multiple reads allowed, but writes are exclusive) involved, possibly with versioning, to prevent users writing outdated files. This can be implemented using a database.
It's important to use a database or a persistent storage if you will scale up to more than one instance of your backend app. In this case, the 2 or more instances need to share the same locks globally. Otherwise threading and basic locks in Python should suffice.
Probably more details of how the files should be used, especially for writes, would allow us to provide better and more detailed solutions.

The files contain information and consist of the following: a user can consult a file, but I want to ensure that it can only be accessed after a user saves changes to it, to avoid errors. Similarly, I would like that if 2 administrators are writing information and both press the save button in the frontend, one should be processed before the other to avoid issues, I was investigating and I found that for web apps and file handling is good to use asyncio with a lock, have ou use it?.

I was also thinking about save the information in a table in a database instead of files to avoid that like you said, is there race condition like that in databases?

Databases deal with race conditions themselves. Yes, it prevents 2 users writing at the same time, but it doesn't mean it solves all the problems. Imagine 2 users opening the document to write at the same time. After the first user commits their change, the second user still has the old version of the document. Should the 2nd user simply overwrite? Or should they receive an error? Or should their version of the document be updated in real time, like it happens in Google Docs for instance?

Using asyncio with a lock works well if you know that only one instance with the backend will run. But this just doesn't scale. If you will ever spawn the second instance of the backend, those locks won't be shared. The only way to share the lock is to use a database entry as a shared lock between the 2 or more instances. Using asyncio with Python locks is indeed much more simple, but again, it only works if there is always a single backend process running.
